# Special characters in selector scss?

Tags: sass, character

How can I print to css a selector compile from scss like this:

SCSS

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root {
    .class_name {
        property: value;
    }
    .multi_class_another {}
}
```

CSS

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .class_name {
    property: value;
}
```

It always shows:

CSS

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media .class_name,_:future .class_name,:root .class_name {
    property: value;
}
```

Comment: What version of SCSS are you using? I don't see that problem using he latest version. See this pen https://codepen.io/sitrobotsit/pen/NgKByW

Comment: Sorry, I don't say clearly. Now, see my update. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In SCSS, when you nest a class within a group of comma separated selectors, the nested class gets applied to all of the selectors. Also, empty classes will be removed.

So, if

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .class_name {
    property: value;
}
```

is what you want the CSS to look like, then, there is no more efficient way to write this is SCSS. If you wanted to make it super clean (and not have that `:root .class_name` nesting on the last selector) then you could look to use Sass's placeholder selectors. More info here http://thesassway.com/intermediate/understanding-placeholder-selectors

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I understand that.

Comment: You're welcome. If it works for you, feel free to accept my answer :)